# Intel XDK hierarchical table

Tags: intel-xdk, hierarchical

Graphs and Maps are well done through Intel XDK tools. 
Is there a 'nice' hierarchical table (like in wijmo 5) tool to handle a hierarchical 'down edge' with drill up and down?

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like Wijmo and jQuery UI with the XDK. You may not be able to use them with App Designer, but you can create your HTML/CSS layout using other tools or by hand. You are not required to use App Designer to build a Cordova app with the XDK.